# retrieving original movie size on client / server side

Tags: javascript, flash

Is there a way to retrieve flash movie size on client / server side?

Assuming I have various games from many providers and I don't know the size of it,

but when I place  on my html page I wanna hit correct size.

Comment: do you mean the size that the movie's stage was compiled to or the size that the player's embed tag is set to?

Comment: I hope we can control the size at the client side in object / embed tags whatever the flash movie size is. Can't it be?

Comment: @AhmedMustafM, I'm not sure what you mean. You can get info about the size of the embed rectangle, but you can't display the movie in a size different than how it is embedded... you're stuck with whatever dimensions you set in the embed/Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP on server side you could use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) method.

Then you can create embed code accordingly.